# How to add property at the end in one .properties file

Tags: java, properties, eclipse-plugin

I am using the below code to write a property in a .properties file.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = file.getContents();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        properties.setProperty(propertyKey.trim(), propertyValue.trim());
        File file1 = file.getRawLocation().makeAbsolute().toFile();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
        properties.store(outputStream, null);
        outputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CoreException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Though it is adding the property in a sorted position but not at the end .But I want it will always be added `at the end`.How can I get that ?

Comment: Since you appear to be using `IFile` you should be using `IFile.setContents` to save the file. Your current method will leave the file out of synchronization with Eclipse.

Comment: Yes,u r right.it is showing file out of synchronization with eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Properties file java doc, you can find the its using HashTable to store key value pair, the order of the key is nor guaranteed. Hence you need to use File Operations once its done you need to reload the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileWriter` to append to the end of file (second parameter of constructor defines appended mode):

```
try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
    out.append(property + "=" + value);
}
```

Comment: Thank u.But it is appending existing content of the file also.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1,true);
```

The true tells it to append the new content to the end of the file.

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Comment: Thank u.But it is also appending existing file content of the file.

Comment: @Anu Check once what data is present in your properties object. I guess youa re loading the entire file content into it and thats why it is appending the existing file contents too. Just make sure you only have the key that you need in the property object.